# Different Evaluation of Seemingly Same Tensors

Tags: tensorflow

In my program I have:

```
run_plain = neural_network_model(x)
run_max = tf.argmax(run_plain, 1)
```

and

```
run_network = tf.argmax(neural_network_model(x), 1)
```

`run_max` and `run_network` give me different outputs when executed with the same input, e.g. via `run_max.eval({x:[test_x[i]]})`.

Is there some fundamental flaw about how Tensorflow `eval()` works that I am misunderstanding - because in my opinion the results should be the same or is there some other error in my code?

Comment: Could you reformat the code? It looks like you're assigning run_plan after run_max in the first example.

Comment: Is it possible that `neural_network_model` changes the values of some variables?

Comment: You have to flip the lines in the first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your whole example?

Otherwise based on what has been given there should be no difference between the two examples.